# DATA_SOURCE USING BULK INSERT in SQL Server does not compile

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm trying to load data from a sample file, but I'm using couple of parameters in the WITH clause and hence it does not compile.

**I'm using SSMS18, Not sure if that is an issue?**

**Not Working:**

```
BULK INSERT #data
FROM 'sample.csv'
WITH 
    ( 
    DATA_SOURCE = 'SampleData',
    fieldterminator ='|', 
    rowterminator = '0x0a',
    FORMAT = 'CSV'
    ) 
;
```

**Working:**

```
BULK INSERT #data
FROM 'sample.csv'
WITH 
    ( 
    --DATA_SOURCE = 'SampleData',
    fieldterminator ='|', 
    rowterminator = '0x0a',
    --FORMAT = 'CSV'
    ) 
;
```

If I comment out the DATA_SOURCE then it works but If it has either DATA_SOURCE or FORMAT = 'CSV' then it does not compile

Here is the error from **SSMS 18** using Sql server version as below:
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4583460) - 13.0.5103.6 (X64)   Nov  1 2020 00:13:28   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 19042: )

> Error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure FDB_Load, Line 262 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Incorrect syntax near 'FORMAT'.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "' data_source_name ' Applies to: SQL Server 2017 (14.x) CTP 1.1 and Azure SQL Database. Is a named external data source pointing to the Azure Blob storage location of the file that will be imported." What are you actually trying to do with that parameter? `FORMAT = CSV` was also added in 2017. And the version of SSMS (the client app) is mostly irrelevant

Comment: You need to post the result of `select @@version`.

Comment: Here is my sql server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4583460) - 13.0.5103.6 (X64)   Nov  1 2020 00:13:28   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19042: )

Comment: @Charlieface, thank you so much for your response, I'm using SQL Server 2016 so you are right.

Comment: @DaleK, I'm using sql server 2016